# Não consigo fazer conexão com o banco de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Olá boa noite estou estudando php, porém na hora de fazer conexão com o BD, não conecta de jeito nenhum, os nomes do banco estão corretos, o ja importei o banco e nada alguém sabe o que pode ser?

**Conexão com o Banco de Dados**

```
<?php

   /**
  * classe que trata de conexao com o BD e operações
   */
   class Conexao {

private $host;
private $user;
private $senha;
private $bd;
private $link;
public  $query;
public  $lista;
//private $tabela;


/**
 * funcao construtora que inicia o link caso esteja null
 */
function __construct() {



    if ($this->link == NULL):
         $this->getConexao();

    endif;


}

/**
 * faz a conexao caso não tenha valores no LINK
 */
public function getConexao(){

    $this->host  = 'localhost';
    $this->user  = 'root';
    $this->senha = '';
    $this->bd    = 'imob';


  $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->senha) or die('Erro de conexao');
  mysql_select_db($this->bd, $this->link);
        mysql_set_charset('UTF8', $this->link);

}


/**
*
* @param type $sql -  passo a minha sql
  */
   public function ExecSQL($sql){

   $this->query =  mysql_query($sql, $this->link) or die(mysql_error());


}

 /**
 *
 * @return type -   retorna a lista de registros
 */
    public function ListarDados(){



            $this->lista = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->query);

    return $this->lista;


}

   /**
  *
    * @return type -  retorna a contagem dos registros s query
    */

public function TotalRegistros() {

    return mysql_num_rows($this->query);

}

  }
```

Comment: **Usuário** e a **Senha** ? Ficaria mas fácil se você [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/275078/edit) a pergunta e colocar o código. Recomendo você a fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona a **comunidade** e a acessar a sessão [Perguntando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Leia [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579).

Comment: eu coloquei o mysqli, mas mesmo assim o banco não conecta

Comment: A porta do serviço MySQL está correta? Utilize `mysqli_connect_error` para verificar qual o erro. É mais fácil de corrigir o problema.